# distributed lock with limited number of process can use

Tags: caching, redis, locking, hazelcast, distributed

I am looking for a distributed lock framework that has a feature like, only limited number of process can use this lock.

For example:

```
Lock lock =new Lock("key", 5);
```

Only 5 process can use this lock at the same time, others has to wait until one of them finishes its job.

Do you know that kind of a framework or how can I implement one with existing ones ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). Most major Redis and Hazelcast clients have already implemented this. For example, in Java, you have:

https://redisson.org/glossary/java-semaphore.html

https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/isemaphore